# Can't submit fixes to iPhone app submitted through iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, application-loader

I submitted my first app to Apple through iTunes Connect, and it got rejected because of two bugs. I fixed the app, archived it, and submitted the latest build through Application Loader. Now when I log in to iTunes Connect, click My Apps > myApp > Activity, I see the latest build listed there, right above the first build. My problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to submit the latest build for review. I tried submitting again, but now on the Activity page, I see that the first build is in review, and not the second one. I submitted thinking that the App reviewers would be able to see the latest version, but the way the Activity page is set up, it seems that I just resubmitted the version that got rejected. Did I do this right? If not, what am I doing wrong?

Here's a screenshot of the Activity page:

[image]

As you can see, Version 1.0 is the one that's waiting for review, but I want Version 1.1 to be reviewed, not Version 1.0. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have to click on the App Store tab, select the currently submitted build.  There should be a button along the lines of "Remove from Review".  Scroll down on that version, under "Build" see if you can remove the 1.0 build and add your 1.1 build.  If this isn't possible, you'll want to click the "+ Version or Platform" to create a new version, and add your new build to that version.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ReplacingYourAppWithANewVersion.html

Hope this helps.